# subir 3 archivos desde 3 input diferentes a BD en laravel

Tags: laravel, controller

Como puedo subir 3 imágenes que se seleccionan desde 3 input de tipo file y almacenarlas en campos diferentes en la base de datos?
en mi controlador he intentado retornar lo que se guardará en la base de datos pero el nombre de las imagenes no se obtienen, solo la descripcion que tambien se almacenará en un campo.

Este es mi controlador:

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $config = ConfigPage::findOrFail($id);
    return $newConfig = $request->all();
}
```

Estoy en el metodo Update porque en realidad necesito editar el contenido que ya tengo en mi tabla, este contenido lo agregué directamente en la base de datos no desde otro formulario.

y esta es el codigo de la vista:

```
@foreach ($configs as $config)
    {!! Form::model($config, ['action'=>['ConfigPageController@update', $config->id], 'method'=>'PATCH', 'files'=>true]) !!}
        <div class="header-page p-3">
            <img src="/images/{{$config->logo1}}" alt="" id="prevImage">
            {!! Form::file('logo1', ['class'=>'form-avatar', 'id'=>'selectImage']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="content-page-custom mt-5">
            <h4 class="text-center">Logo</h4>
            <img src="/images/{{$config->logo2}}" alt="" id="prevImage2">
            {!! Form::file('logo2', ['class'=>'form-avatar', 'id'=>'selectImage2']) !!}

            <h4 class="text-center">Imagen de Página</h4>
            <img src="/images/{{$config->image_page}}" alt="" id="prevImage3">
            {!! Form::file('image_page', ['class'=>'form-avatar', 'id'=>'selectImage3']) !!}

            <h4 class="text-center mt-3 mb-2">Descripción</h4>
            {!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'rows'=>'4', 'required']) !!}

            {!! Form::submit('Guardar', ['class'=>'btn-form mt-4']) !!}
        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endforeach
```

Y esta es la vista en la pagina para entender mejor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito ayuda por favor :(...

Answer (score 1):

Esto es variante, ya que puedes tanto guardar la imagen dentro de un fichero en tu proyecto, como también podría ser en la misma base de datos. Te voy a dar un ejemplo de cómo lo hago yo, que es con ficheros.

**Blade:**

```
<input type="file" name="img_cedula" required>
```

**Controlador:**

```
// Se le asigna a una variable el request de la imagen
$img_cedula = $request->img_cedula;

// Se valida que exista y si existe se le asignará un nombre
if($img_cedula){
$img_cedula_name = 'cedula'.$request->cedula.'-'.time().$img_cedula->getClientOriginalName();

// Se guarda la imagen en el fichero
Storage::disk('cedulas')->put($img_cedula_name, File::get($img_cedula));
}
```

El nombre que le quieras asignar al archivo queda a tu gusto.
Una vez tengas el nombre del archivo, tienes que usar la variable `$img_cedula_name` para que esa se guarde en la base de datos.

**Fichero:**

La configuración de este la encuentras en **app/config/filesystems.php**, yo tengo lo siguiente en la sección de **'disks'**:

```
'cedulas' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/cedulas'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Deberás crear una carpeta dentro de **storage/app** para que se te guarden las imágenes

**Método para acceder a la imagen:**

```
public function getCedula($filename){
        $file = Storage::disk('cedulas')->get($filename);
        return new Response($file, 200);

    }
```

**Ruta:**

```
Route::get('/imagen/cedula/{filename}', 'SolicitudController@getCedula')->name('solicitud.imgcedula');
```

**Llamar la imagen en Blade:**

```
<img src="{{ route('solicitud.imgcedula', ['filename'=>$solicitud->img_cedula]) }}">
```